# Play the video only when completely downloaded

Tags: html, video, buffer, loader

I would like that my video loads only when it has been completely downloaded by the browser (in fact, I don't want that it starts to play when only few seconds was buffered, my video is only 45 seconds and about 3Mb). I use the following code, but it seems that I need something else:

```
<video id="video" width="798" height="600" controls preload>
```

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967921/html5-video-loader-progress) where someone mentioned that he had used a script which cover the video until it's completed and then fadeout when it's ready. I think it could be the workaround I'm looking for. Someone can help me to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

You want to respond to this event:
oncanplaythrough

Comment: Hi Nurne, thank's for your answer. So i try this, but it's seems that Safari doesn't handle it or I miss something:
<script type="text/javascript">
       function addMyListeners(){
       var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
       myVideo.addEventListener('progress',getPercentProg,false);
       myVideo.addEventListener('canplaythrough',myAutoPlay,false);
       }
 
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="addMyListeners()">
<div>
<video width="798" height="600" controls>
<source src="video.mp4">
</video>
Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Jerome, does the src of the video element point to a valid video file? Try responding to the event in the old inline way and see what happens: <video ... canplaythrough="playMe()"></video>

Comment: did it help? please choose answer if it did :)